# Объявление глобального string

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Здравствуйте! Пересел с C# на C++, а конкретно: создаю Windows Forms app.

```
 Private System::Void Form1_Load () { 
   String^ one;
 }

 Private System::Void Button1_Click() {
   label1->Text(System::Convert::ToString(one));
 }
```

Не видит `one`. Делал `public`, но тут как-то не то. Неужели придется читать книгу? Думал с C# пересесть будет легко.

Comment: а почему ему видеть локальную переменную другого метода? Или в шарпе видит?

Comment: Это кстати не C++,  а Managed C++.

Comment: Точнее не ANSI-ISO C++, а C++\CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String^ one;
```

Эта переменная объявлена у Вас в процедуре Form1_Load и область видимости там же находиться. Как же Вы собираетесь к ней получить доступ из другого метода?!

Перенесите объявленение one в класс.